# Where should I check after I set up environment variables for rails cron named “Whenever”?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, cron, whenever

CentOS 6.8
Ruby on Rails
Cron: Whenever

I set up environment variables for DB name, DB password and DB host. I am sure those variables show up with env command.

But I cannot use them in rails codes or yaml files like <%= ENV["DB_NAME"] %>. They are nil. When I put DB name in database.yml directly, it works. There are logs saying "No database selected" something like that. I understand the logs because <%= ENV["DB_NAME"] %> is nil but I don't know how to solve it.

Generally, Where should I check if my setting is fine for rails cron named "Whenever"? or Could you tell me how to set up correctly?

Comment: How did you set up the environment variables? Did you source the file after that? If you set them up correctly they won't be nil.

Comment: I used Ansible to set up the variables to centOS on AWS. I executed "source /etc/profile" but it doesn't work. But logs said "No database selected".

Comment: What is the result of `printenv | grep DB_`?

Comment: DB_HOST=xxxxxxx
DB_USER=xxxxxxx
DB_NAME=xxxxxxx
DB_PASSWORD=xxxxxx

Comment: The "rails way" to do database configuration via env vars is [by using `ENV["DATABASE_URL"]`](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/configuring.html#configuring-a-database).

Comment: Could you elaborate on that? I believe host, user, DB name and password need to connect to database. Could I use ENV["DATABASE_URL"] for DB name?

Answer (score 0):

You should export that environment variable in /etc/environment